# Cannot resolve method 'formKey' in ACRA 4.7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, acra

i tried setting up acra for my android project today, but it didnt work. I followed the instructions, importet the acra lib in gradle (compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0')
Then i added this:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "mail@adress.com", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.NOTIFICATION)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ACRA.init(this.getApplication());
```

I get the error **Cannot resolve method 'formKey'**, but when deleting formkey from parameters, i get **@ReportsCrashes not applicable to method**

I also tried

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.yourselectedbackend.com/reportpath")
```

and

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", formUri = "http://www.yourselectedbackend.com/reportpath")
```

and get the same errors. Anyone knows the issue/solution? The wiki at https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki seems outdated and there is no issue about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`formKey` has been removed for some time. I don't know where you saw instructions to use it, but they should no longer exist too. Use `formUri`.

You are getting `@ReportsCrashes not applicable to method` because you have annotated your *onCreate* `method`. You need to annotate your Application `class`

Comment: The instructions are still there: On the [home page](http://www.acra.ch/): "The formKey parameter was used for the now deprecated GoogleDocs Forms backend. It is still required but not used anymore." and in the [Wiki](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage).

Comment: OK, I'll get those references removed. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me Thanks.. I faced this issue when i updated acra , before to this , i was using it as jar.