# Not able to generate signed apk. Proguard throwing error

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am successfully able to generate the debug apk of my Android app. But while generating a signed version I get the message:

Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task

':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Following is the list of my project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: add this line

-dontwarn ch.acra:acra:4.5.0.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[methodscount.com](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=ch.acra%3Aacra%3A4.5.0) shows, that `Acra` (v 4.5.0) depends on:

```
org.json:json:20080701
```

You have two choices:

1. Update `Acra` to version 4.7.0

or

2. Add this dependency

Comment: Now in my application class I am getting an error in "formKey "

Comment: Then probably the second option might be a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157752/cannot-resolve-method-formkey-in-acra-4-7-0

Comment: I updated Acra to 4.7.0 and it worked. Thanks...This is the correct answer